# How to run .net 6 api in docker server core

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I would like to run .net 6 api, java runtime and nodejs in same docker image. I installed java in servercore docker image, it run I expected. And I deployed .net 6 in aspnet docker image, then it worked. But I can not deploy .net 6 api and java in same  servercore docker image. How can I deploy .net 6 api in server core image?

**UPDATE:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022-amd64 as base
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

## Install .net
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile dotnet-sdk-6.0.102-win.exe https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/fb14ba65-a9c9-49ce-9106-d0388b35ae1b/7bbfe92fb68e0c9330c9106b5c55869d/dotnet-sdk-6.0.102-win-x64.exe; \
    Start-Process "dotnet-sdk-6.0.102-win.exe" -ArgumentList "/passive" -wait -Passthru; \
    Remove-Item -Force dotnet-sdk-6.0.102-win.exe

## Install Node
 ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.14.0/node-v16.14.0-win-x64.zip C:\\build\\node-v16.14.0-win-x64.zip
 SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]
 RUN Expand-Archive C:\build\node-v16.14.0-win-x64.zip C:\; Rename-Item C:\node-v16.14.0-win-x64 node
 RUN SETX PATH C:\node

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Source/Business/OnlineIde/OnlineIde.Api/OnlineIde.Api.csproj", "Source/Business/OnlineIde/OnlineIde.Api/"]
COPY ["Source/Business/OnlineIde/OnlineIde.Application/OnlineIde.Application.csproj", "Source/Business/OnlineIde/OnlineIde.Application/"]
COPY ["Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.DataAccess/Infrastructure.DataAccess.csproj", "Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.DataAccess/"]
COPY ["Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.Interfaces/Infrastructure.Interfaces.csproj", "Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.Interfaces/"]
COPY ["Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.Domain/Infrastructure.Domain.csproj", "Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.Domain/"]
COPY ["Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.Core/Infrastructure.Core.csproj", "Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.Core/"]
COPY ["Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.WebApi/Infrastructure.WebApi.csproj", "Source/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.WebApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Source/Business/OnlineIde/OnlineIde.Api/OnlineIde.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Source/Business/OnlineIde/OnlineIde.Api"
RUN dotnet build "OnlineIde.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "OnlineIde.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OnlineIde.Api.dll"]
```

I am building with the `docker build . -t servertest` command. Then I am trying to run with the `docker run --name servertest -p 5000:80 -d servertest` command. Node is running installed. But when I try to go to localhost:5000/swagger it gives error 'This site can't be reached'. Do I need to grant firewall permission?

Comment: sorry what are you trying to do?

Comment: I made an online compiler project with asp net for several language. Now, I am trying to dockerize this project. That's why I need to run java, node, go and csharp sdks and asp net api project in the same docker image.

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile to your post

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: @MattThalman I added the Dockerfile. Thank you :)

Comment: @HansKilian I added the Dockerfile. Thank you

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this? I am currently trying something really similar and do not understand how to do it. Thank you!